# Enable or Disable selectboxes with radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have set of radio buttons and set of select boxes dynamically generated through PHP code but I am using same class name for the respective radio button and select box like.

```
<input type="radio" name="selop" class="1111" />
<select name="selval" class="1111"><options><!--All options--></options></select>
<input type="radio" name="selop" class="2222" />
<select name="selval" class="2222"><options><!--All options--></options></select>
<input type="radio" name="selop" class="3333" />
<select name="selval" class="3333"><options><!--All options--></options></select>
<input type="radio" name="selop" class="4444" />
<select name="selval" class="4444"><options><!--All options--></options></select>
```

In my case the name for all the radios and the name of all select boxes are same and class names for each set are same.

I want like if some one checked the a radio the select box of same class should be enabled and rest should be disabled.

I tried this way which didn't work for me.

```
var $radio = $('input[name=selop]:checked');
var cname = $radio.attr('class');
var classname = "." + cname;
$(classname).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

First when radio button state change, add disabled attribute to all select box and then  remove the attribute for particular select box

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name=selop]').on('change', function () {
        var $radio = $('input[name=selop]:checked');
        var cname = $radio.attr('class');
        var classname = "." + cname;
        //console.log(cname);
        $('select[name=selval]').attr('disabled', 'true');
        $(classname).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/7KAXN/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
  $(function(){
     $('input[type=radio]').on("change",function(){
     var classList=$(this).attr('class');
     var selector='select.'+classList;
     $(selector).attr('disabled',false);
     $('select').not(selector).attr('disabled',true);
   });  
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/voravaqu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

My solution that disables all selects except the checked one: http://jsfiddle.net/9dHqJ/

HTML:

```
<input type=radio name=selop>
<select disabled><option>Foo</option><option>Bar</option></select>

<input type=radio name=selop>
<select disabled><option>Foo</option><option>Bar</option></select>

<input type=radio name=selop>
<select disabled><option>Foo</option><option>Bar</option></select>

<input type=radio name=selop>
<select disabled><option>Foo</option><option>Bar</option></select>
```

JS:

```
$('input').change(function () {
    $('select').attr('disabled', true);
    $('input:checked + select').attr('disabled', false);
});
```